# Firefox scrolls page when I use arrow keys to scroll search results from Google, Youtube, ebay, etc

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-search

I recently made the switch from Chrome to Firefox (more specifically the 64 bit Waterfox because Chrome doesn't make a 64 bit variant). Anyways, I noticed that when I used Chrome to search Google, Youtube, Ebay, or any other website with a search box, hitting the down arrow while typing would select the suggested search result. Firefox seems to do that also, but in addition it scrolls the page like it normally would if I wasn't typing. It's not a huge issue, but it is annoying and keeps me from seeing what search term I selected. I was wondering if there was any fix for this problem.

[FULL DISCLOSURE]

I am running Waterfox 16 (same as Firefox 16), but I have tried it on Firefox Nightly (Version 20) and no fix seemed to be implemented by then either.

Comment: That's odd, it does not scroll down for me (tried it in the latest version of Firefox in a clean profile). Can you reproduce this in safe mode?

Answer (score -2):

This Tip Is About Setting configuration of firefox means it applys to all pages on firefox.
type in url **about:config** now in search box type **general.smoothScroll** you'll find lots of properties named with same just do values as u like. 
There are pixels, Mousewheels , keys set whatever u want.

Comment: Quite an irrelevant answer.